# Using Python to connect to SharePoint via App sign-in (Client ID, Secret & Tenant ID) to Write or Read Files

Tags: python, authentication, sharepoint, read-write

Connecting to SharePoint to Write/Read Files through App Sign in Method (Client ID, Secret & Tenant ID) but wouldn't be able to get authenticated.

I have tried the code below:

```
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
context = ClientContext(SITE_URL).with_credentials(
                      ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))

cert_credentials = {
    "tenant": TENANT_ID,
    "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
    "thumbprint": test_cert_thumbprint,
    "cert_path": "{0}/../selfsignkey.pem".format(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
}
ctx = ClientContext(test_site_url).with_client_certificate(**cert_credentials)
current_web = ctx.web.get().execute_query()
print("{0}".format(current_web.url))

from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

class SharepointService:



        app_principal = {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET}

        context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=site_url)

        token = context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=app_principal['client_id'], client_secret=app_principal['client_secret'])
        print(token)

        ctx = ClientContext(site_url, context_auth)

        web = ctx.web
        ctx.load(web)
        ctx.execute_query()
        print("Web site title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title']))
```

[Got this error when i tried running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCdeM.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to following code to write or read files

```
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version

# Replace these values with your SharePoint information
site_url = "https://your-sharepoint-site-url"
client_id = "your-client-id"
client_secret = "your-client-secret"
tenant_id = "your-tenant-id"

# Specify the site version (2013, 2016, Online)
version = Version.v2016

# SharePoint library and file information
library_name = "Documents"
file_path = "/Shared Documents/YourFile.txt"

# Connect to SharePoint
authcookie = Office365(site_url, username=None, password=None).GetAppOnlyAccessToken(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id)
site = Office365(site_url, authcookie=authcookie).GetSite()

# Open the SharePoint library
sp_library = site.List(library_name)
sp_library.GetListItems()

# Read file content
file_content = sp_library.get_file(file_path).read()

print("File Content:")
print(file_content.decode("utf-8"))

# Write to file
new_file_content = "Hello, SharePoint! This is a new content."
sp_library.upload_file(file_path, new_file_content.encode("utf-8"))

print("File has been updated successfully.")
```